# WebGL2RenderingContext Error when trying to run Typescript with tsc file.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, yarnpkg

I just installed Typescript using both npm and yarn on my Windows 10 machine, and when I run 'tsc file.ts' I get an error that says '582 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext'.

It directs to the directory ../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:16485:13

Furthermore, It says 16485 declare var WebGL2RenderingContext: { 'WebGL2RendingContext'was also declared here. Found 1 error.

Here is the screeshot from Node.js Command Prompt

[image]

Comment: But you don't run WebGL on server side - right?

Comment: `AppData/Roaming/npm/` you have installed it global - you have to install it local for your project.

Comment: @Zydnar, I'll have to check, maybe some of the other apps I'm running might be using WebGL, I'll try installing it locally... Visual Studio, Chrome and Groove Music are open at the same time

Comment: The problem still persists after installing typescript locally

Comment: Ok, now read the error message two declarations collide - can you show your tsconfig - lib.dom.d.ts collide with @types/webgl2

Comment: I add "checkLib": "true", from another user's Question where they said Tensorflow was creating the conflict. The issue on Github also says it could be that there is a clash between the Window Object and Global Object of the same names. I have tried uninstalling JQuery and Tensorflow but the problem persists.

Comment: Here is all you need: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webgl2/index.d.ts - one solution would be extend WebGL2RenderingContext from lib.dom.d.ts with following properties, just remember about license

Comment: jQuery does not use WebGL2, but Tensorflow does, I think it's not the problem. If this error blocks you consider using //@ts-ignore comment and come back to it later.

Comment: It compiles, I could just run it with 'node filename', but I want the tsc hello.ts to run in the CLI, I tried the comment in my file, but it still persists

Comment: This was my first question - you can't run WebGL outside browser in CLI, sorry it's not possible.

Comment: Commented out the Function Declaration of the specified Line, It worked

Comment: You mean it transpiled into JS, not runned.

Comment: Exactly, It does not console.log. Can I run it directly, is it supposed to run directly or do I use Node? Because it did transpile before, minus the error code... I am wondering if the WebGL is supposed to the output and I switched it off

Comment: I am installing ts-node, I guess that's what it's for... And ts-node filename.ts works. Thanks a lot Zydnar! You've been very helpful

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this problem executing this line.

```
npm i --save @types/webgl2
```

Answer (score 1):

If your declarations collide try to import declaration you need:

```js
import {WebGL2RenderingContext} from "webgl2"
const lol = (ctx: WebGL2RenderingContext)=>{/* do sth*/};
```

with @types/webgl2 problem is it have no exports, so you have to change it a bit:
just add export before `declare` keywords.

Comment: Great, Will keep that in mind when using WebGL2RenderingContext

Answer (score 0):

I could not have solved this problem without Zydnar's Help, Thanks to Him. After some deliberation, I decided to comment out the WebGL2 Rendering Function and It worked, It transpiled to javascript and I ended up using ts-node filename.ts to run the code.

Thanks once again to @Zydnar, You were very helpful.

Comment: Commenting out it's bad practice and after any dependencies update you will have the same problem.